# Get the count of items inside a drawing in autocad using VBA

Tags: vba, autocad

I am trying to get the number of items present inside the model space.
If i am not mistaken the `Count` does that trick, but I am not able to make it work (I might be wrong).

For example, `Set entity = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(0)` gets only the first item. and `Set entity = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item(0)` gets the second. But how to know how many we have ?

I tried `ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count` but it gives the below error when running it.

[image]

Comment: Silly question: did you try `ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count`?

Comment: What about a `For Each Item in ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Item`?  Possibly wrong syntax.

Comment: Guys The solution for this was to use ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count but set it inside an Integer variable. it worked now using----- Dim X As Integer ; X = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count

Comment: @tony9099 Add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Guys The solution for this was to use `ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count` but set it inside an Integer variable. it worked now using the below

```
Dim X As Long
X = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Count
```

Comment: You might consider upping that to a Long instead of an Integer, otherwise you might regularly run into overflows.